# Only show the values that does not exist in the other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one with functions and one with used functions. I have a query which only has to show me the values which are not used. So it has to compare if the function name exists in the other table, if not show that value.

For example this is my database table **functions**:

```
function_id | function_name | function_description
1           | function_1    | lorem ipsum
2           | function_2    | dolor sit amet
```

And this is my table **used functions**:

```
register_id | function_activation | function_deactivation | etc
1           | function_1          | function_1            | lorem ipsum
```

So like function_2 does **not** exist in the **used functions** table. I used this query to check it:

```
SELECT * FROM functions WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT function_activation, function_deactivation FROM used_functions)
```

But it shows me nothing. Am I using a wrong query or maybe something else?

Comment: Which are relation columns between this tables ?

Comment: They don't have relation colums, I just read the documentation and i'll make a relational column. I think that's just the problem. @OtoShavadze

Comment: I'll update my question when I'm done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery.

```
SELECT functions.* FROM functions LEFT JOIN used_functions
  ON functions.function_name = used_functions.function_activation
  WHERE used_functions.function_activation IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM functions WHERE function_name NOT IN
 (SELECT function_activation FROM used_functions)
```